# iOS Swift Data Design Confusion

Tags: ios, swift

As an exercise in learning Swift/iOS, I have begun coding an adaptation of a mildly complex adventure board-game. In this game, players often end up with cards that represent objects. Each such card has a rule associated with it, usually fairly simple. There are well over 100 unique cards.

In laying out my coding design, I keep running into the same problem, along the following lines:

```
Class ItemCard {
    var name: String = “motorcycle”
    var cardImage = << filename information for where the card image is >>
    << rule: maxSpeed += 3 >>
}
```

Now if I do this card by card, it’s easy enough, but it’s also an insane amount of code to do very, very little. Absolute brute-force method. At base, this isn’t any better:

```
    switch cardName {
    case “Motorcycle”:
        << call the motorcycle function >>
    case “Boat”:
        << etc. etc. etc. >>
    }
```

Obviously I can abstract somewhat: all cards that adjust certain kinds of stats call function adjustStat(nameOfStatAdjusted, byHowMuch). But somewhere I still have to have an extended definition that says that objects which are instances of .motorcycle take this function, which reverts me right back to brute force lists of every single item with a longish stream of code.

It seems to me that there has to be a clean way to:

1. Put the relevant data into some kind of list files from which it can be extracted exclusively when a player draws a given card, and then de-initiated when that card leaves play for one reason or another; AND
2. Have appropriate base classes for different kinds of cards, different general categories of items, etc.

... and all of this without using 10+ lines of code for every single card individually.

What am I misunderstanding about data structures in iOS? Is this something I should be doing with CoreData or Realm or something?

Answer (score 0):

> using 10+ lines of code for every single card individually

You exaggerate. The card *type* may have *slots* for multiple pieces of info (name, image, rule, etc.), but each individual *card* is going to be initialized *once* by *one* line of code. So, 100 cards means 100 lines of code. And you only have to type those lines once. So I don't see the problem.

Look at it like this. Suppose our program needs to use the names of the 50 US states, which it is to store as an array of strings. It isn't going to know those names by magic. Somewhere, somehow, we need to have constructed and provided a list of those names. You can code that as 50 lines of code that build an array, or you can write a 50-line text file and have the program read it and cycle through it to construct the array. But either way, the data has to get into the program *somehow*, so *somewhere* there are 50 lines.

(Of course, if the card features can be generated by some sort mathematical rule, the number of lines can be reduced by looping. For example, a 52-card deck of playing cards involves an arithmetic sequence 1 through 13. However, it doesn't sound like your deck is susceptible to that; it's more like a bunch of individually defined cards, like Magic the Gathering or Tarot. So there has to be a list of all the details *somewhere* in your program.)